# Comparing Two SQL Tables Based On Matching Column

Tags: sql

I have two tables, T1 and T2. T1 looks like this:

```
    ID      Type      Date
    _____________________________
    1       CA        11-17-2018
    2       BA        7-12-2018
    3       CA        4-1-2018
    4       BA        1-17-2018
    5       CA        9-30-2018
```

And T2 looks like this:

```
    ID      Type      Date
    _____________________________
    1       CA        11-17-2018
    2       BA        3-1-2018
    3       CA        4-1-2018
    4       CA        1-17-2018
    5       CA        10-3-2018
```

I need a way to compare rows from the two tables that have matching IDs and see if the other values match or if they're different. I only want the output table to contain those IDs with differing values, and display those values. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a pretty simple query using a `join` and `where` criteria...

Comment: Please specify database engine you're using in tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Type as T1Type, T2.Type as T2Type, T1.Date as T1Date, T2.Date as T2Date
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.DATE <> T2.DATE
OR T1.Type <> T2.Type
```

Notice that this query will only return result where the `ID` is present in both tables.

Comment: @tjc i answered this question before this user but you accept this answer any reason ????

Comment: @tjc strange activity

Answer (score 1):

I think you need below something, `inner join and comparison`

```
  select T1.*,T2.* from T1 inner join T2 on T1.id=T2.id
    where T1.Type!=T2.Type   and T1.Date!=T2.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use `join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
where (t1.type <> t2.type) or (t1.date <> t2.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put one foreign key in one of this tables, who will make reference to the other.

When you make a select, you can do a join of one table with other by the primary key and the foreign key.

```
SELECT column FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id_pk = table2.id_fk WHERE condition;
```

in WHERE you put something like

```
WHERE (table1.id != table2.id) OR (table1.type != table2.type) OR (table1.date != table2.date);
```